# Recently reinstalled Visual C++ Redistributable, many programs are now broken, how do I fix?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-c++

Ever since I reinstalled my Visual C++ redistributables in an attempt to fix another issue, many of my programs that use this dependency have become nonfunctional.

I am infuriated because every single "solution" I can find just instructs on a Visual C++ reinstall or manual .dll file replacement.

I reinstalled it by going into Programs and Features and clicking all versions of Visual C++, right-clicking them, and then clicking uninstall. I am on Windows 10.

My father also seems to have had similar issues which he could also not resolve via simply reinstalling Visual C++. He could only solve it by formatting his PC, which I really don't want to do.

I have had three issues:

- Adobe InDesign refuses to start up due to a runtime error (the initial error that prompted me to reinstall Visual C++).
- GTAV refusing to start due to files MSVCP140.dll and VCRUNTIME140.dll missing. Checking the System32 folder shows that both .dll files are present.
- War Thunder Asset Viewer crashing when loading a model, error message says something about vcruntime

I have tried various fixes such as:

- Installing all older versions (2008~2019)
- Installing Visual C++ as administrator
- Manually replacing the .dll files with online downloads.
- Reinstalling the dysfunctional software (GTAV, War Thunder Asset Viewer)

All solutions known to me are ineffective and I am at my wit's end.

Comment: You have not reinstalled, but rather uninstalled. We don't know what exactly you did, and which files you deleted. If System Restore is enabled, you could try and rollback to a restore point from before this was done.

Comment: The Visual C++ Redistributable is version dependant. This is why you can have multiple installs of them on your computer and its important they all stay installed. Removing one will break all programs that rely on that specific version to work. You will have to reinstall all broken programs, or at least the VC++ redist that came with their installs.